# What is the Taylor expansion of $f(x) = \sqrt{x^2-1}$ around $x=1$?

Tags: taylor-expansion

## Question

What is the Taylor expansion of $f(x) = \sqrt{x^2-1}$ around $x=1$?

The first derivative of $f(x)$ is $f'(x) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$, but when $f'(1)$ is evaluated, the denominator is zero.

### Result by `python sympy`

Then, I have tried the first derivative of $f(x)$ by `python sympy` and it gives me the following result:
$$- \sqrt{2} \sqrt{t - 1} - \frac{\sqrt{2} \left(t - 1\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{4} + \frac{\sqrt{2} \left(t - 1\right)^{\frac{5}{2}}}{32} + t + O\left(\left(t - 1\right)^{3}; t\rightarrow 1\right)$$

I am wondering how to obtain this result by hand.

I would appreciate it if you could help me with this problem.

Note: The code to calculate the Taylor expansion is as follows:

```
from sympy import symbols, sqrt, series, latex

t = symbols('t')

g = t - sqrt(t**2 - 1)

taylor = series(g, t, 1, 3)
latex_style = latex(taylor)
print(latex_style)
```

Comment: $f$ is not differentiable at $1$ so it doesn’t have a Taylor expansion, but what you can do is write $f(x)=\sqrt{x-1}\sqrt{x+1}$ (provided $x>1$), and for the $\sqrt{x+1}$ part, write its Taylor expansion around $1$, so now you have $\sqrt{x-1}$ times some Taylor expansion.

Comment: @peek-a-boo  Thank you for your answer. I have learned that the results of Taylor expansion by `python sympy` and Wolfram Alpha are based on the same idea, which rewrite $f(x)$ and do the Taylor expansion for some part.

Comment: This is a [Puiseux series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puiseux_series).

Comment: @Gray Thank you for you answer. I have understood that Puiseux series is a generalization of Taylor series to implicit functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x=t+1$ and work
$$\sqrt{2 t+t^2}\qquad \text{around}\qquad t=0^+$$

$$\sqrt{2 t+t^2}=\sqrt{2t}\left(1+\frac{t}{4}-\frac{t^2}{32}+\frac{t^3}{128}-\frac{5
   t^4}{2048}+\frac{7 t^5}{8192}+O\left(t^6\right) \right)$$

The numerators and denominators form respecively sequences $A002596$ and $A123854$ in $OEIS$.

If you prefer a recurrence relation, use
$$a_n=-\frac{(2n-3) }{4n}\,a_{n-1} \qquad \text{with}\qquad a_0=1$$

Comment: In other words, there is no Taylor expansion.  You might as well mention it :-)

Comment: Thank you all for your answers and comments. I have understood that A002596 and A123854 are both the taylor expansion of $\sqrt{x+1}$ around $x=0$.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to say it is around $x=1$.

Comment: @XYJ. This is what I did. Now, replace $t$ by $(x-1)$ to get the Puiseux series.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks. It was first time for me to hear about Puiseux series, so I want to learn more about this.